# Old paranoid man with uncut hair and fingernails

Tags: identify-this-movie, character

I have seen multiple references to this character, mainly in cartoons.

What movie is this character originally from?

The character is a paranoid, sleep deprived old man with long hair and long nails who's constantly watching the surveillance camera.

I have seen a reference to him on The Simpsons, which looked like this:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is usually artistic license in the depiction of someone with a severe phobia of germs. In the particular case where the individual in question is very rich, as with Mr. Burns in The Simpsons, it is almost certainly based on [Howard Hughes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howard_Hughes) rather than on any movie.

Comment: In fact the plane model that *Burns* develops in this episode consolidates the *Howard Hughes* reference even further.

Comment: And even further than in "Springfield (Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love Legalized Gambling)" in "Midnight Rx".

Comment: @Tom - where I live, "license" is a always verb, and "licence" may be either a noun or a verb.

Comment: Never seen it spelled that way (neither as noun nor verb.) But if you believe the edit is erroneous, roll it back or re-edit it.

Comment: I'm bilingual - I can live with the American English spelling.